# JavascriptRouter Method with parameters

Tags: javascript, scala, jquery, playframework, fullcalendar

First of all I am totally new to the whole domain of web application development so please excuse if my question seems really trivial (my knowledge of HTML/JavaScript/CSS/jQuery/AJAX is very limited but I am eager to learn).

I am currently developing a web application using [playframework](/questions/tagged/playframework) 2.2.0 with [scala](/questions/tagged/scala). I needed a calendar module on one page so after a bit of researching on the web I stumbled across [fullcalendar](/questions/tagged/fullcalendar) which I use (or try to use) in version 1.6.4.

Now the problem I am experiencing is I need to somehow pass the parameters of the callbacks of the calendar for lets say the `dayClick` event to my controllers. I searched the web on how to do this and found out I should use the `javascriptRouter` provided by play. Now everywhere in every example the methods that are used are parameterless and I dont seem to get it to work with my controller method that takes a parameter.

Is it the case that I cannot create reverse routes for methods with parameters and pass the values that way or am I missing something?

And if it is not possible what is the best way to pass parameters from the calendar to my scala controller methods?

I have seen [the seemingly popular example of fullcalendar with play on github](https://github.com/biesior/Play-20-Sample-FullCalendar-Java) but using these hidden forms seems like such a pain for something that should be a fairly simple task in my opinion (also I dont really understand where the code is that actually submits these forms)

My implementation:

```
object Application extends Controller {
  def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
    import routes.javascript._
    Ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")
       (routes.javascript.CalendarInteraction.day)).as("text/javascript")
  }
}
```

In routes:

```
POST    /day/{date}         controllers.CalendarInteraction.day(date: String)
```

in CalendarInteraction:

```
def day(Day: String) = Action {
  println(Day) //just for testing
  Ok(views.html.interaction(Day)) //Also just for debugging
}
```

and I try to get the values from this callback:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
calendar.fullCalendar('changeView',"agendaDay");
$.ajax("/day/"+date); // does not work
//HOW???
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting I found the solution to my problem which was rather simple as it turned out.

I changed my route to:

```
POST    /day/:date              controllers.CalendarInteraction.day(date: String)
```

and the callback function to:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {               
    calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
    calendar.fullCalendar('changeView',"agendaDay");
    jsRoutes.controllers.CalendarInteraction.day(date).ajax();
}
```